# Is $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{R},\{N(\mu,1): \mu \in \mathbb{R}\})$ a complete statistical structure?

Tags: statistics

Let $B \in \mathcal{R}$ and $N(\mu,1)(B)$ a free event, wich means it doesn't depends on the unknown parameter $\mu$. Then prove that $B$ or $B^c$ is $N(\mu,1)$-null.

I've alredy proven that if the statistic structure is complete, then the only free events are P-null or complementary.
A complete statistic structure is the one that every centered($E_\mu T =0$) real statistic is P-equivalent to zero, i.e. $P_\mu (T^{-1}(\{0\}))=1$.